# How to determine which tab was right clicked on?

Tags: c#, tabs

I have seen this question asked multiple times, all with the same answer. For some reason it does not work correctly in my program.

This is the basic answer that everyone gives to this question...

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabs.TabCount; ++i) {
    if (tabs.GetTabRect(i).Contains(e.Location)) {
     //tabs.Controls[i]; // this is your tab
    }
}
```

This is the same code that I am using but when I right click on the second tab, it always closes the first tab.

When I debug the problem, this is what I get...

```
e.Location: x=57, y=7
rect(0):    x=2, y=2, width=56, height=18
rect(1):    x=58, y=2, width=99, height=18
```

[image]

As you can see the location (2 + 56 = 58) is in the first tab even when I click on the second one.

What am I doing wrong? This code is repeated so many times I find it hard to believe that it doesn't work. It looks like the e.Location is starting from a different location than where the tab starts.

UPDATE: This is the routine that I am running when you right click on the tab to bring up the context menu.

```
private void cmpClose_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    OpenPDF currentOpenPDF;

    // iterate through all the tab pages
    for (int i = 0; i < tcDocuments.TabCount; i++)
    {
        // get their rectangle area and check if it contains the mouse cursor
        if (tcDocuments.GetTabRect(i).Contains(e.Location))
        {
            // Do something to the tab
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which location yields clicking on the upper left corner of the first tab?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a Winforms application, and you're using the standard Tab control that comes with Winforms.  But it's not clear how your Click event handler is attached ... are you handling the Click event on the Tab control itself, or one of the Tab Pages, or the Form itself?  The "e.Location" origin is going to depend on which control you're handling the Click event on.  Please provide more detail, as well as what you're trying to achieve overall.  There may be easier ways than trying to do hit testing with mouse click locations.

Comment: I am using the mouseup event on a context menu, but the cursor is positioned over the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your e.Location value you get from the ContextMenu has no relationship with the rectangle area of the TabPage header.

Try storing the value in the TabControl's MouseUp value:

```
Point tabMouse = Point.Empty;

void tcDocuments_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  tabMouse = e.Location;
}
```

Now you can just use the proper Click event of the menu item:

```
void printPDFToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  for (int i = 0; i < tcDocuments.TabCount; ++i) {
    if (tcDocuments.GetTabRect(i).Contains(tabMouse)) {
      // do your stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selected event for the TabControl and pull the selected tab from the EvenArg.

```
private void tabControlStudent_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e) 
{
  if (e.TabPage == tabPageGuardianInfo)
  {
    loadGuardianList();
    selectGuardian();
  }
  else if (e.TabPage == tabPageTransactionInfo)
  {
    loadTransactions();
    loadPaymentAccount();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to require that the tab be selected. Thanks

Comment: So you would like to have the what tab was clicked but not necessarily selected? I see in your title you say clicked but in the question body you say right clicked. You would like to capture the right click even on the unselected tab?

Comment: Yes. I know how to tell if it was right or left clicked so I didn't make that distinction in the title.

Comment: Might be worth updating your question to remove any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As Rajeev pointed out in the comments, we can't see how your click event handler is attached, so it might be the problem. Doing the below works for me.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.tabControl1.MouseClick += tabControl1_MouseClick;
}

void tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
       {
           if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).Contains(e.Location))
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Right Clicked on tab {0}", i);
           }
       }             
   }
}
```

Update: Looking at the click locations vs rectangles, I get the same as you, although I change of tab only when the location is 58 even though at 56 I should theorically be above tab 1. This happens because they overlap, the active tab will be above the other one(s) by 2 on each sides.
[image]

The locations for both instances above:

```
Right Clicked on tab 0
{X=57,Y=7}
{X=2,Y=2,Width=56,Height=18}
{X=58,Y=2,Width=99,Height=18}

Right Clicked on tab 1
{X=58,Y=7}
{X=2,Y=2,Width=56,Height=18}
{X=58,Y=2,Width=99,Height=18}
```

Comment: This does not work, please read the original question.  I have updated question to include the Mouseup routine.